# Laravel passport - Allow user to act as/login as other user

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I'm working on an application where some users should have access to other user accounts. For example: In a family, the mother and all 3 kids have an account. Now the mother should have access to all of the kids accounts.

Is there a possibility to setup something like this in Laravel using Passport? I thought about a "permission" database table with two columns (parent_account, child_account). Parent accounts could then switch between accounts where they have the permission.

Perfect would be something like a middleware where I can set `Auth::actAs($child);`and after that every `Auth::user()` call would be the child until I switch back to the "normal" account.

Additional information: I'm using Laravel to provide an API for my React Frontend Application. I tried the `Auth::loginUsingId` function, but when I use it I get logged out and I get the `Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::loginUsingId does not exist.` Exception.

I am using Laravel Version `6.9.0`

Comment: Please specify your laravel version.

Comment: @AlexandrBiship See my edit - v6.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

I added a middleware that contains this piece of code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $activeChild = Auth::user()->activeChild; // id of child user

        if ($activeChild) {
            Auth::setUser($activeChild);
        }

        return $next($request);
}
```

After that I added this middleware to all routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['actAsUser']], function () {
     // some routes
});
```